# "because" or "so"

Tags: conjunctions

> We can combine these two clauses in two different ways. (using [Because and so](https://www.englishgrammar.org/because-and-so/))

can we change *because* with *so* in the following sentence? and Is this applicable on all sentences that have *because* **in the middle** (between two clauses)?

Is there any difference in meaning?

> We can't go to Julia's party **because** we're going away that weekend.

> We're going away that weekend **so** we can't go to Julia's party.

Also I noticed that *so* used more in news website. Is it more formal?

Comment: The sentences you're trying to connect are not the same, so it doesn't make much sense to compare them. They only happen to mean almost the same thing.

Comment: No no, they're not wrong. Both are grammatically correct. I'm just saying the latter clause in each case is different, so comparing them isn't going to teach you anything you don't already know.

Comment: @M.A.R. I don't got it. aren't that have the same meaning?

Comment: I think they have the same meaning. But ... I'm an English starter.

Comment: They have the same meaning, but that doesn't mean they use the same grammar. I can say "I tried to make omelette for breakfast" in a lot of different ways and they still would mean the same thing and be grammatical. You've grasped the use of ''so'' and ''because'' and that's all that matters.

Comment: @M.A.R. - I think the OP is asking for confirmation that the two sentences mean roughly the same thing. We seem to think they do. But I think it's a fair question for a learner to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have grasped the basic concept.  "Because" is used mark the *cause* in a "cause and effect" sentence:

> I didn't ride my bike to work (*effect*) **because** it is raining (*cause*)

In the same way, "so" is used to mark the *effect* in a "cause and effect" sentence:

> It's raining (*cause*) **so** I didn't ride my bike to work. (*effect*)

Same action, different direction.  Regardless of where it appears in the sentence, "because" precedes the cause.  In the same way "so" precedes the effect (and usually comes immediately after the cause).

Other examples:

> Because chicken is on sale at the market, let's buy a lot and freeze it for later
>
> Chicken is on sale at the market, so let's buy a lot and freeze it for later.
>
> I can't play for you at your party, because I left my guitar at home.
>
> I left my guitar at home so I can't play for you at your party.